# Почему сайт открывается, если изменены важные настройки файлов nginx?

Tags: nginx

Есть рабочий сервер
на нем стоит node.js nginx и подключено бесплатное шифрование Certbot

имею файл:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/funprograms.ru`

````
``` server {
listen 80;
server_name funprograms.ru www.funprograms.ru;
rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
server_name funprograms.ru www.funprograms.ru;
index index.html;
access_log /var/log/nginx/funprograms.ru.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/funprograms.ru.error.log error;
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funprograms.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funprograms.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot
ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

location / {
client_max_body_size 100m;
client_body_timeout 600s;
client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 16K;
proxy_connect_timeout 70;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
proxy_read_timeout 90;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header host $host;
proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
}```
````

имею для него ссылку в:

```
 `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`
```

nginx.conf:

````
``` user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```
````

для проверки изменения конфигурационных файлов выполняю:

```
`sudo nginx -t`
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`
```

Если я беру и тупо убираю в файле /etc/nginx/sites-available/funprograms.ru вот этот участок:

````
```
**server {
listen 80;
server_name funprograms.ru www.funprograms.ru;
rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}**
```
````

и даже делаю далее :

```
`
**server {
server_name _sdwerw;
#index index.html;**
`
```

То сервер работает как и работает без каких либо изменений.
Что это такое, как будто закешированы данные и ничего на самом деле не изменяется. При этом, если файл удалить или удалить, например само слово **server_name**, то тогда nginx ругается.
Запускал с разных браузеров.
Не понимаю почему изменение настроек никак не отражается на работе.

Comment: Я хочу добавить второе доменное имя к сайту, чтобы работал сертификат шифрования. Или нужно как-то делать перенаправление URL второго доменного имени?

Answer (score 0):

Вся конструкция

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name funprograms.ru www.funprograms.ru;
rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

делает редирект с http://funprograms.ru на https://funprograms.ru, уберите это код из конфига, перезапустите nginx и сайт http://funprograms.ru будет недоступен, а https://funprograms.ru будет работать. Иногда современные браузеры самостоятельно запрашивают https для сайта, поэтому возможно вы не видите разницы когда отключаете код.

Comment: Поскольку в коде явно указаны заголовки hsts, браузер который хоть раз загрузил этот сайт в дальнейшем всегда будет сразу ходить по https. Так что такие вещи правильно проверять либо на чистом профиле браузера, либо вообще при помощи curl/wget и прочих консольных утилит которые не умеют hsts